# How to have two lookup to feld (Country and Town) - Sharepoint List - Add new Object

Tags: sharepoint, office365

[image]

I have created a default list
and two extra list

: Country
Countryname

: Town
Town - Countryname (Lookedup from Country)

But now when i go into by Default list (Country is lookedup from CountryList and Town is Lookedp from TownList)

But when i start a new object it will not filterout the towns thats not related to that country

I Use sharepoint from Office365.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are looking for is a [cascading dropdown](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-alternatives-to-building-cascading-drop-downs-in-sharepoint/).

As for SharePoint Online modern list, we are not able to create a cascading dropdown in modern experience with Out-of-box solution. If you have access to PowerApps, you can use it to customize the list form. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzvMbmb5pmo) for your reference.

And here is a [thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint/m-p/9948) discussing with some solutions and workarounds about it.